# Updating a the session of a specific user on CakePHP

Tags: session, cakephp

I have a case where an admin can edit some user information, which might belong to a logged in user. I need to ensure that the other user's Auth info updates to reflect the new changes. It seems like, currently, Auth info is static unless manually updated. Is there a way to manually update Auth info (essentially the session), not of the current user, but of a known user?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to input from Mark Story, the most straightforward method seems to be the following:

1) make sure you're using database sessions...

```
Configure::write('Session', array(
    'defaults' => 'database',
    'handler' => array(
        'model' => 'cake_sessions'
    ),
));
```

...a schema like the following will work fine:

```
CREATE TABLE `cake_sessions` (
    `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `id` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    `data` text,
    `expires` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

2) Save the user's id to the `user_id` column. Do this by creating a file called `cake_sessions.php`, and saving it in your `Model` directory. The file should contain something like the following:

```
<?php 
    class cake_sessions extends AppModel{
    public function beforeSave($options = array()){
        if ( AuthComponent::user() ) {
            $this->data[$this->alias]['user_id'] = CakeSession::read('Auth.User.id');
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Then it becomes trivial to simply delete the desired session, based on `user_id`.

Comment: Or using an [own table](http://www.dereuromark.de/2010/09/17/keeping-track-of-usersguests/) for this - as with this you can also save a little bit more meta data and don't need to mess with the default cake_sessions table. But the idea is the same.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think that is directly possible with CakePHP libraries because it looks like a very special use case. The ways you can go about this is -

1. Put a flag i  your users table and switch it once the details are updated, for every request using the AppController's beforeFilter just check this flag for that user and regenerate the session data.
2. If you are storing your session data in the database you might be able to update it from there (or delete it to force user to login). I am not sure how cakephp stores it in the database. Else if you go for files for session  data you can scan through them for the user id you want to update.

Updating a user's session externally is generally not the preferred mechanism and is considered to be a hack, try thinking of any possible workarounds.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what your exact use case is here, but I agree with using the beforeFilter in the AppController to check for a flag. It might not be desirable to query the database every page load for this check, that might not be a concern in your case, but if it is you can look into CakePHP's caching. In Config/bootstap.php you can setup additional caches and key them based on the user's id, then in the model you can place logic in a beforeSave() or afterSave() to clear that users cache file. Then the beforeFilter in the AppController can check for the cache file and if it is missing you know you need to build a new cache file and pull that data into your session. I use something along those lines for ACL caching in CakePHP. I build a cache for each user and load their permissions into their Session, if the ACL permissions change the cache is rebuilt.

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/caching.html

Comment: "It might not be desirable to query the database every page load for this check." That was my reluctance. In my case, there are athletes who belong to teams. A coach from one team might add an athlete to their team, and if an athlete is logged in when that happens, I need to ensure that their Auth data is up-to-date

Comment: There is really no way around the check, but using cake's caching should improve performance. In this case you would be checking for a missing cache file and if it is missing build a new one. It gets deleted when the coach makes an update to the athlete. Look into model callback methods, as that is the best place to clear the cache.